# CMake: include Lemon library

Tags: cmake

I just want to add the Lemon library to my CMakeLists.txt. When I was not using CMake I just added "-lemon" and everything went fine, but now I don't know the procedure to add that to the CMake file.

Edited do include my **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# Created by the script cgal_create_cmake_script_with_options
# This is the CMake script for compiling a set of CGAL applications.

project( ssp )


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.2)
if("${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}" VERSION_GREATER 2.6)
  if("${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_PATCH_VERSION}" VERSION_GREATER 2.8.3)
    cmake_policy(VERSION 2.8.4)
  else()
    cmake_policy(VERSION 2.6)
  endif()
endif()

set( CMAKE_ALLOW_LOOSE_LOOP_CONSTRUCTS true )

if ( COMMAND cmake_policy )

  cmake_policy( SET CMP0003 NEW )  

endif()

# CGAL and its components
find_package( CGAL QUIET COMPONENTS  )

if ( NOT CGAL_FOUND )

  message(STATUS "This project requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.")
  return()  

endif()

# include helper file
include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )


# Boost and its components
find_package( Boost REQUIRED )

if ( NOT Boost_FOUND )

  message(STATUS "This project requires the Boost library, and will not be compiled.")

  return()  

endif()

# include for local directory

# include for local package

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lemon")


# Creating entries for target: ssp
# ############################

add_executable( ssp  arrangement.cpp main.cpp polygonOperations.cpp scheduleGraph.cpp )

add_to_cached_list( CGAL_EXECUTABLE_TARGETS ssp )

# Link the executable to CGAL and third-party libraries
target_link_libraries(ssp   lemon ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES} )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple, use [target_link_libraries](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries):

```
project(test)

add_executable(mine test.c)

target_link_libraries(mine m)
```

Where in this example, I'm linking against libm. In your case, `m` would be `lemon`. At least I think, I'm not sure from your question if the library name is `lemon` or `emon` since `-l` is the flag and the name should follow (ie `-lm` links libm).

For my simple example, if I run `make VERBOSE=1` (and strip out the unimportant lines):

```
[100%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mine.dir/test.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/mine.dir/test.c.o   -c /home/tgallagher/temp/test.c
Linking C executable mine
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/mine.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc      CMakeFiles/mine.dir/test.c.o  -o mine -rdynamic -lm
```

So it compiles the source file first, then it puts the `-lm` on the linker line.

Comment: The library's name is really `lemon`. But when I run the `make` command, now I get the error `clang: warning: -lemon: 'linker' input unused when '-c' is present`

Comment: @MauricioZambon Since it's just a warning, does the resulting executable still work?

Comment: Nope, it's not linking the library.

Comment: What does `make VERBOSE=1` show for the compile line that generates the warning?

Comment: `/usr/bin/c++   -DCGAL_USE_MPFR -DCGAL_USE_GMP -lemon -O3 -DNDEBUG -I/opt/local/include -I/Users/.../Code    -o CMakeFiles/ssp.dir/scheduleGraph.cpp.o -c /Users/.../Code/scheduleGraph.cpp`

Comment: Something funky is going on with your CMakeLists.txt. Can you edit your question with it in there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20347/discussion-between-tpg2114-and-mauricio-zambon)